# iPod shuffle 3rd gen doesn't shuffle well

Tags: ipod-shuffle

I recently got a Mac and I synced my iPod shuffle with it. I have around 300 songs on my iPod but despite the fact I set the playing order to shuffle, the iPod doesn't shuffle the items very well. It plays 3 songs from every album in a row.
How do I make sure it shuffles well?

Comment: are those three songs rated 5 stars in iTunes?

Comment: 3 songs of every album, i've not rated any song